# MS-Graph API, How to use a single "get" API method call to fetch multiple extended properties with different propertyIds from a contact?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

While testing MS-Graph for contacts, i tried using two API calls to get business fax and company main telephone number:

**Business fax:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/contacts?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x3A24')
```

**company main telephone number:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/contacts?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x3A57')
```

Is there a way to get both of those in the same call? I want to get all extended properties visible in office 365 contacts view. Something like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/contacts?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x3A24') and singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x3A57')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to Group your extended properties inside the filter and use an OR eg the following works for me

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(PropertyId eq 'String 0x3A24') or (PropertyId eq 'String 0x3A57'))
```

beta example using id

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties(filter=(id eq 'String 0x3A24') or (id eq 'String 0x3A57'))
```

Comment: Thanks Glen Scales. I received the same error "Parsing Select and Expand failed." I am not using "me" though. My code has app access.

Comment: Glen Scales. I made a mistake. Your example does not work with beta, but it does work with v1.0!! Thank you!

Comment: Beta doesn't seem to like you using PropertyId vs id, I've included a sample that should work okay in beta

Comment: Using id in place of propertyId wiith beta did remove the error, but it did not include these two items in the returned value as extended properties or anywhere else that I could see. Thank you for update.

Comment: I can see those props okay in beta, there is some other weirdness happening in beta I'm getting Autocomplete or suggested contacts entries returned. If you just try it against a specific contact that you know those properties exits on using that contacts id does it work ? eg https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/contacts('a...')?$expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=(id eq 'String 0x3A24') or (id eq 'String 0x3A57'))

Comment: After testing beta, I could not find the extended properties using a call for all contacts or a single contact with the properties in question. It does not throw an error and it does not return the properties. Also I get weirdness with beta as well. It's as if it's a version of the people api instead of contacts api.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the in operator instead of the eq one to get all the properties that have an id matching the list you provide.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}/contacts?expand=singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId in ('String 0x3A57','String 0x3A24'))
```

Comment: Thanks baywet. I received the error message "Parsing Select and Expand failed." Any thoughts?

Comment: Hum apparently the in operator might not work with this specific API segment